# JSOM get site from GUID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jsom

Using JSOM how can get the  URL like the powershell script below using the site GUID

```
$web = get-spweb -Site 87d28faf-a0ac-4ac6-80a1-96aca53d07b7
$web.Url
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSOM Code snippet to get all sites url based on a web application:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadWebs, "sp.js");
function loadWebs() {
    enumWebs(['Url'],function(webs){
        for(var i = 0; i < webs.length;i++){
        //console.log(webs[i].get_url());
            $("#AllWebUrls").append("<p>"+webs[i].get_url()+"</p>");
        }
    },
    function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
}
function enumWebs(propertiesToRetrieve, success,error){
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var rootWeb = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
   var result = [];
   var level = 0;
   ctx.load(rootWeb,propertiesToRetrieve);
   result.push(rootWeb);
   var colPropertiesToRetrieve = String.format('Include({0})',propertiesToRetrieve.join(',')); 
   var enumWebsInner = function(web,result,success,error){
      level++;
      var ctx = web.get_context();
      var webs = web.get_webs(); 
      ctx.load(webs,colPropertiesToRetrieve);
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < webs.get_count();i++){
                var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                result.push(web);
                enumWebsInner(web,result,success,error);
            }
            level--;
            if (level == 0 && success)
              success(result);  
        },
        error);
   };
   enumWebsInner(rootWeb,result,success,error);    
}
</script>
<div id="AllWebUrls"/>
```